# trouble with bluetooth on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

It seems I can't get any bluetooth devices working in ubuntu 16.04 at all, not just bluetooth mice.

headphones, phone, and two bluetooth mice (one being a roommates) have failed to connect using the built in bluetooth dialog.

mid edit edit: I got my phone to the point where ubuntu gives me a message that it successfully paired, but the phone gave an error saying it couldn't pair. Don't know what to make of this.

Now I have absolutely no idea how to diagnose this at all, so here's <strike>wonderwall</strike> the output of "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb"

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095b] (rev 61)
     Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5210]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1bcf:2c79 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0483:91d1 STMicroelectronics Sensor Hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 056a:5055 Wacom Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2516:003c  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

<strike>I just got an MX Master, partly because of the multiple bluetooth connections it can support (I dual boot)</strike>

Unfortunately it seems that newer bluetooth devices have trouble on ubuntu.

It seems [this fellow here](https://www.ralf-oechsner.de/opensource/page/logitech_mx_master) has an answer on how to make it work...
which falls apart on the first line "hciconfig hci0 sspmode 0" which gives the error "Can't set Simple Pairing mode on hci0: Input/output error (5)"

I like this mouse since it seems to be the only "smart" bluetooth mouse that doesn't lag in winbdows and osx for me. It would be a shame if I couldn't get it to also work with linux since I'm spending more and more time here.

Comment: Does the bluetooth adapter work in Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you mean the unifying adapter? I've not tried to use it yet as the entire idea was to NOT have a dongle taking up a precious usb port on my laptop. I could try to but even if it works it would be of no use since it still doesn't work the way it's mean to.

Comment: I mean the internal bluetooth adapter. Does it work with other devices?

Comment: That's actually a very good question. I've never tried it with anything else since I've never needed any other bluetooth things connected. I just tried it with my bluetooth headphones however, and, at the very least, the standard bluetooth dialogue gave me the same error "setting up "foo" failed" Good call

Comment: OK. Then please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: edit done. Thanks a bunch for helping Pilot6!

Comment: I am puzzled. This chipset should be well supported.

Comment: I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this issue stems from a lack of support for HFP/HSP and A2DP profiles on the Broadcom BCM20702 chipset, unless a proprietary firmware file is loaded into it to enable this functionality. Some users have reported success using [this firmware](https://s3.amazonaws.com/plugable/bin/fw-0a5c_21e8.hcd) and placing it in `/lib/firmware/brcm`

With some versions of the kernel It's **required** to rename the file to match the complaint from `dmesg` which **might** be:

> Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd failed with error -2

If this is your case simply `mv /lib/firmware/brcm/fw-0a5c_21e8.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd` or whatever filename the kernel is complaining about in `dmesg`

Reboot as a final step.

Note: I do not have your hardware available for testing. This answer is based strictly on research.

Sources:

https://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2015/10/msg00083.html

https://plugable.com/2014/06/23/plugable-usb-bluetooth-adapter-solving-hfphsp-profile-issues-on-linux/